# List of Lists to 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting

i need to convert this list: `List<double[]> test = new ArrayList<>();`

to an 2 dimensional Array with an structure like this :

```
double[][] test2 = {{3.17, 26.348}, {3.65, 24.198}, {3.28, 25.085}, {3.37, 22.461},
{2.57, 23.740}, {3.60, 24.786}, {3.50, 23.374}, {2.98, 23.725},
{2.54, 23.227}, {3.41, 26.920}..........};
```

i already tried things like this but it did not work :

```
List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();

    double[][] matrix=new double[x34.size()][];
    matrix=list.toArray(matrix);
```

Comment: If you have a `List<double[]>` why doesn't the `list.toArray(matrix)` approach work for you if `matrix` is a `double[][]`? Of course if you're starting with a `List<String[]>` you'd need to parse the strings to `double` as well which requires some more coding on your end.

Comment: if i try it that way my array is filled with null values ....

Comment: Your original list is a `List<double[]>` or a `List<String[]>`?

Comment: You might want to show a [mcve] to show your approach. Of course the list needs to contain data and the size of the target array needs to match the size of the list.

Comment: ahh i got it thank you i made a mistake on this part "list.toArray(matrix);" i did not refere to my list

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 11 or higher, each collection class has a `toArray` method which you can use. Example:

```
List<double[]> myList = List.of(new double[]{3.17, 26.348},
                                new double[]{3.65, 24.198},
                                new double[]{3.28, 25.085},
                                new double[]{3.37, 22.461});

double[][] result = myList.toArray(double[][]::new);
```